# Updating database with real-time windowed aggregations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming pipeline that consumes a streaming source (Kafka) and will write to a CloudSQL database. The goal is to keep the CloudSQL database updated in real-time with a Key/Value sum aggregation of records received in the past hour.

eg. In the last hour 3 records with KV `<001,3>`,`<001,4>`,`<001,2>` were recieved, database should have a record `001, 9`. Records older than an hour aren't included.

My current solution a SlidingWindow into a GroupByKey after the `KafkaIO.read`:

```
                    .apply(Window.into(SlidingWindows
                                .of(Duration.standardSeconds(3600))
                                  .every(Duration.standardSeconds(20)))
                    ).apply(GroupByKey.create())
```

Followed by a ParDo that sums each key, and then update the SQL database.

The result is that every 20 seconds my CloudSQL db is updated with the aggregation of each key of the last hour, which meets the functional requirements. The issue is the amount of upserts to CloudSQL this causes: most of the KV outputs are identical to the previous window, so each window every 20s triggers an hours worth of transactions (~500k).

It would make sense to trigger each KV output only when a record with that key is consumed, or avoid outputting the KV's which have not changed since the previous window. Or, some sort of filter before the CloudSQL insert that takes in everything and that only outputs changed KV's. Is this possible or is there another solution?

Comment: Have I understood correctly that on average every hour there is data for 0.5M keys? 
The KV should  already only be outputting data if that <K> has had an element in the last hour. Is it possible that all 0.5M keys do actually have a value every hour? 

In terms of only changing if a value is different, you will need to start looking at the State API, but would be good to confirm the above to make sure nothing unexpected is happening first.

Comment: Yes that's right. No data older than the window time is getting output, only keys that have data received in the last hour. Not all possible keys may be seen in a given hour window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible method to explore would be to make use of the State API downstream of your sliding window aggregation.

However elements flowing into the this are unordered, so you can not just store the element and compare it with the incoming value.

- You will need to add each element in the DoFn to a BagState (as a Timestamped Value).
- Set a Timer and then during the the OnTimer() function read all the elements in the bagstate sort them and output the values you need. You will also need to store the max(timestamp) value in a ValueState object so that you can use it the next time the OnTimer is called.

The size of the window you use for the State API DoFn will be arbitrary, the larger it is the less unneeded upserts. On the downside the larger the window the more keys you will keep around in the ValueState which may no longer be needed. Avoid using the Global Window as this will require you to build in a GC function as the window will never expire and your key space will grow forever.